# cannot enter my own directory after running 2 commands

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm not too abreast on all Linux commands and following a pretty thorough tutorial on setting up WP on my ubuntu 20.04.

I ran these 2 commands :

```
sudo find /var/www/wordpress/ -type d -exec chmod 750 {} \;
sudo find /var/www/wordpress/ -type f -exec chmod 640 {} \;
```

And now I can't enter the directory:
`-bash: cd: wordpress/: Permission denied`
How do I fix this?

`www` dir as follows:

`drwxr-x--- 5 www-data www-data 4.0K Jun 12 18:56 wordpress`

> EDIT: I'm on an AWS server as default ubuntu user and sudoer, even with sudo I cannot enter that dir.

Comment: can u please add output of this command in your question:    ls -ltrh

Comment: @shahabvalizade those 2 find commands had no output. When I `cd wordpress` I get `-bash: cd: wordpress/: Permission denied`

Comment: I mean whats the output of (ls -ltrh) command on /var/www or parent folder.

Comment: by seeing this I am assuming I need to do something with the www-data group?

Comment: If you are a sudoer you should be able to cd wordpress now. first try (sudo -i) then run your cd command

Comment: @shahabvalizade I just added ubuntu to www-data group but I still get permission denied when trying to cd into that dir, how can I cd into dir as `ubuntu` user?

Comment: @shahabvalizade I did `sudo usermod -a -G www-data ubuntu` and still permission denied

Comment: You have to be user `www-data` or in the `www-data` group.  If you have added user ubuntu in the group (using `usermod` above), you have to logout and log back in to "trigger" the change.  If you `id -a` you will see the entire group assignment of your user.

Answer (score 0):

You should run the command below to be able access /var/www/wordpress and then trying to cd into it.
`$ sudo chmod 755 /var/www/wordpress`
As changing to specific directory requires executable permission on that directory.
Hope it solved your problem.